# Python printing hierarchy

Tags: python

```
print(f'Name Entered: {print(f'{input("Enter a name: ")} '*int(input("Enter a number: ")))}')
```

Output:

```
Enter a name: Tom
Enter a number: 3
Tom Tom Tom 
Name Entered: None
```

Supposed to be `Name Entered: Tom Tom Tom`

For learning purposes, in this code for example, why does this happen and how can I solve this kind of issue while keeping it one line?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You used `print` two times. Maybe this helps:

```
print(f'Name Entered: {input("Enter a name: ") * int(input("Enter a number: "))}')
```

### EDIT (with spaces):

```
print(f'Name Entered: {(input("Enter a name: ") + " ") * int(input("Enter a number: "))}')
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are printing the result of print, which is None.

```
print(f'Name Entered: {input("Enter a name: ")* int(input("Enter a number: "))}')
```

works the way you intended it to

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the output `Name Entered: None` is because the function `print()` doesn't return any value, so when you pass the inner/second `print()` to the outter/first `print()`'s f-string it was literally given no value, thus `None`.

Like the others have also said, removing the inner/second `print` gives us a working version:

```
print(f'Name Entered: { input("Enter a name: ") * int(input("Enter a number: ")) }')
```

As for the lack of spaces between the repeated names (caused by string concatenation), pretty easy fix.
`input("enter a name: ")` gives us a very clean string, e.g. `"Name"`, but no space after it. So what we need to do is `string + " "`, which in your code looks like `(input("Enter a name: ") + " ")`.
The reason for the extra set of parentheses is so that the space (`" "`) isn't multiplied first (by second input value), then added to the name, so specify addition first then multiplication for correct results:

```
print(f'Name Entered: { (input("Enter a name: ") + " ") * int(input("Enter a number: ")) }')
```

Output:

```
Enter a name: John
Enter a number: 4
Name Entered: John John John John
```